# Open the lookup dialog of a field in CRM 2011 from javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

How can I launch the lookup dialog of a lookup field, using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to launch the lookup dialog from a custom page - based on CRM2011 (post Rollup 12).

```
var organizationUrl = "http://servername:5555/organizationName";

//Object Type Code of the entity which needs to be shown in the Lookup.
var objectTypeCode = 1000;

var urlToOpen = organizationUrl + "/_controls/lookup/lookupinfo.aspx?LookupStyle=single&browse=0&showpropbutton=1&AllowFilterOff=1&objecttypes=" + objectTypeCode;

//Get the modal window    
var modalWindow = JSON.parse(window.showModalDialog(urlToOpen, " ", "dialogHeight:600px;"));

//Selected Id will be returned here    
var selectedItemId = modalWindow.items[0].id;
```

Comment: but what if I want to open a custom view instead of the default one?

Comment: You need to pass a defaultViewId parameter in the query string, with the guid of the view (url encoded of course)

Comment: Something like this: ...  &DefaultViewId=%7bA066D18A-8A4A-44EE-B78E-9A870DC799DD%7d& ...

Comment: For some reason it still opens the default view Id... Does it have something to do with the fact that I'm creating the custom view in the js code?